# Rails updating object creating two database transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model I am updating through a form wizard. On the last step, I want to update the object with the form data then call a callback in the model to push the data to an external API. The issue I'm having is that the finall step is saving the data in two transactions.

```
# controller
def update
  @business = current_user
  @loanapplication = @business.loan_applications.last
  @loanapplication.update_attributes(loan_application_params(step))
  params[:loan_application][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
  render_wizard @loanapplication
end

# Model
# Callbacks
after_commit :create_salesforce_loan_application, :on => :update
def create_salesforce_loan_application
  if self.status == 'active'
    puts "create salesforce function running"       
    # Updating business column
    self.business.update_column(:state, 1)
  end
end
```

**database transactions**

```
[paperclip] saving XXX.xlsx
[AWS S3 200 0.101161 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"",:content_length=>29467,:content_type=>"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: FX - Competitive Analysis.xlsx,:key=>"XX.xlsx")  
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
create salesforce function running
SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "state" = 1 WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Business') AND "users"."id" = 55
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  COMMIT
create salesforce function running
SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "state" = 1 WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Business') AND "users"."id" = 55
```

The two commits are making the callbacks in my model fire twice, if I can figure out how to save update the data in the model once, then my callbacks will only fire once. Is there a way I can find out what's causing the two commits?

Comment: Which version of rails you use? I had find this: [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8937) that report your problem.

Comment: @RiccardoDegan I'm using rails 4.1.0

Comment: The ``:create_salesforce_loan_application`` is being called twice because the object is updated twice in the process. Can you verify there is no other callback causing the object to be updated twice? Maybe ``paperclip`` is doing that after saving the file to AWS?

Comment: @dgilperez I'm thinking it has something to do with paperclip too. Will do some research tonight and post back if I find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:create_salesforce_loan_application` is being called twice because the object is updated twice in the process, maybe by other callback or gem such as Paperclip.

A better approach to this would be to use `after_save` instead of `after_commit`, checking if `:status` attribute changed.

```
class LoanApplication < ActiveRecord:Base
  after_save :create_salesforce_loan_application, on: :update

  def create_salesforce_loan_application
    if status_changed? && status == 'active'
      puts "create salesforce function running"       
      # Updating business column
      business.update_column(:state, 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Can you elaborate on why status_changed works in this case?

Comment: Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html methods and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html . Within a transaction, the object knows if some attribute changed. That happens ``after_save``, ``after_create``, ``before_update`` ... but not ``after_commit``, which is fired after the transaction has been commited, so the object attributes are not changed anymore at that point.